# The first order Gorilla Walkers Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

So Why did the first Order in Star Wars build the gorilla walkers and just not use the imperial model At-AT?  Any answer is acceptable.

Comment: Can you please make sure you tag all Star Wars: Last Jedi film questions accordingly. It helps to prevent spoilers.

Comment: Forty-two. You did say that _any_ answer was acceptable, and that’s an all-purpose answer good for all occasions.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Magnetic_harpoon

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of our future work policy.

Comment: Our [Future Works Policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based) is actually to close as Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: [Look Here](http://www.starwars.com/news/inside-two-deadly-new-first-order-vehicles-from-the-last-jedi)

Comment: @Machavity I haven't actually checked the premiere dates for different countries, but I do have a ticket to see The Last Jedi on December 13.

Comment: Why do people ask questions like this? Why does Honda keep making new car models? Why does apple make new iPhones? Why do humans make new military aircraft? Because the new versions are better, dammit. Why did they implement some hokey gorilla hand ambulation system? Because they're impractical and hope that some time in the far future humans will make toys out of their designs

Comment: Voting to reopen because *The Last Jedi* is no longer a future work.  Some visitors of the site have seen that film, as evidenced by https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176257/4918

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed in the film's [Incredible Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections) factbook. There are a number of reasons why the First Order replaced the AT-AT with the AT-M6 but it boils down to it being **a fundamentally upgraded model with better armour, more powerful weaponry and a psychologically more imposing look**.

---

> **AT-M6**
>
> A TOWERING MACHINE seemingly plucked from nightmares, the All Terrain
>   MegaCalibre Six brings devastating firepower to the surface of Crait.
>   Sheathed in state-of-the-art armour forged in secret facilities in the
>   Unknown Regions, the massive AT-M6 is simultaneously a brutally
>   effective siege engine and a fiendish example of psychological
>   warfare. It is a menacing symbol of an emboldened First Order finally
>   unleashed to wreak havoc on the galaxy that rejected its Imperial
>   predecessors. The goal of such an obscene display of murderous power
>   is to reduce enemies to abject terror, incapable of any course of
>   action except total submission.

and

> The AT-M6 is fundamentally a platform for the MegaCalibre Six
>   turbolaser cannon, which dominates the walker's massive fuselage.
>   Intended to make siege warfare simple and short, the M6 is powerful
>   enough to punch through shields rated to deflect bombardment from
>   orbit. Bringing the destructive power of a battleship to ground
>   engagements requires a dedicated power plant and a string of auxiliary
>   fuel cells to reduce the cannon's recharge time.

and

> First Order researchers solved the challenge of how to incorporate the
>   MegaCalibre Six cannon into a walker frame by redesigning the
>   vehicle's front legs. The legs were modified to bear increased weight
>   and to provide the stability needed to brace the craft against the
>   cannon's massive recoil. The vehicle's "knuckle-walking" locomotion
>   has another advantage: it gives the AT-M6 the aspect of a giant simian
>   predator, making an already intimidating weapon even more fearsome to
>   enemy eyes.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the gorilla walkers are simply the regular AT-ATs with different equipment attached to handle walking on salt (which, in theory, would differ from the other canon movie uses: snow and sand)